# simulator for ISA and Exchange server !

Tags: networking, exchange, isa

for educational purpose I need simulator for any version of ISA server and Exchange Server !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can download pre-configured (time-limited) virtual hard drives (to be used with [MS Virtual PC](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/virtual-pc/)) for **[ISA server](http://www.microsoft.com/forefront/edgesecurity/isaserver/en/us/try-it.aspx)** and **[Exchange server](http://www.microsoft.com/exchange/2010/en/us/try-it.aspx)** for free from Microsoft.

Comment: This is not I am looking for !! I want to practice on some tutorials of ISA and Exchange servers.

Comment: Uh, those are full versions of ISA and Exchange servers you can practice on.